# What should be the output after extracting features from an audio signal using DWT (Discrete Wavelet Transform) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, audio, speech-recognition

I am working on a speech recognition system (I'm following a [research paper](http://dyuthi.cusat.ac.in/xmlui/bitstream/handle/purl/3914/PERFORMANCE+OF+DIFFERENT+CLASSIFIERS+IN+SPEECH+RECOGNITION.pdf;jsessionid=0DB3D03E6BB47F8B6789BDBBB8004162?sequence=1)), after denoising the signals I want to extract features from audio signals that are in the form of arrays in MATLAB.

Please correct me if I'm wrong but I think that the size of features array (after performing decomposition) should be smaller as compared to the original audio signal.
I used `wavedec` to decompose the signal upto 10 levels using db8 as the wavelet family, but the output was same in size as the input or slightly larger.

Answer (score 2):

The coefficient array should be the same size as the original.

[image]

If you look at what wavedec does, it breaks down your signal into a high and a low component using 2 filters and then decimates by a factor of 2. It then repeats this on the approximation component (low) for each level you decompose. So if you decompose at one level, you simply pass your signal through both filters and decimate the result by 2 at the end. This preserves the number of total samples. The same logic applies to the next and subsequent levels.

Comment: Yes, I have gone through the logic and they should be the same size, but is this the proper output of 'feature extraction' step? Plus there are a lot of zeros at the end of the output array too.

Comment: Tthe paper claims to use DWT, this is what wavedec does. Are the zeros particularly problematic for some of the later classifiers?

Comment: I'm not a pro at speech recognition, I've never done it before I'm following tutorials to do my project. Apparently most of the tutorials have a lot small feature matrices near to twenties and ours remains as the size of the original signal, this is a problem so I figured we might be doing something wrong.

Comment: It depends on the types of features you are using. Also, just because your feature transform results in a N length feature array, doesn't mean you can't use a M length feature array, which is a subset of the original N. This might actually be helpful for particular features.